# MySQL joins to display member, submember tree structure

Tags: mysql

I have a table called tbl_member,there is a column called parent which defines the parent of that member.But problem is when there is more than child of a root vendor my query it is showing duplicate row.In tbl_member table there can be be n level child.**I want to show the member name and immediate parent name**.Below is my query

```
 SELECT tm.first_name fn,
        tm.last_name ln,
        tm.username ,
        tm.email_id,
        tm.member_password,
        tm.status,
        tm.create_date,
        tm.member_id,
        tm.parent,
        tm.type,
       if(tm2.parent is NULL, 'parent', CONCAT(tm2.first_name,' ',tm2.last_name)) as parent_name
      FROM tbl_member tm
      LEFT JOIN tbl_member tm2 ON  tm.member_id=tm2.parent
      WHERE tm.type='vendor'
```

is it possible in one query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible.  I think your code may be backwards. The join should be `ON tm.parent = tm2.memberId` because tm2 should be the parent record.  Then change your last column to use `tm2.member_id`.